# Select Columns using Case When based on condition - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to select a column based on Case when based on a condition. It was working fine but I don't know how to return the proper alias Name for the selected Column.

For example.

```
If I=1 then
I should select "L.id" with ColumnAlias as LeadId 
else 
I should select "sl.id" with ColumnAlias as ServiceLeadId
```

My output should contain only one column with proper alias like the below.

```
If I=1

LeadId 
1
2
3
...
...

If I<>1

ServiceleadId
1001
1002
1003
...
...
```

I tried like the below

```
select
CASE WHEN @i = 1 Then
                  L.Id AS LeadId
                 Else

                  sl.id AS ServiceLeadId
end
from table
```

but I got an error.

Please suggest me any ideas to achieve this.

Comment: *"but I got an error."* would it be too much to ask to include what error you got in your question?

Comment: Any particular query will always produce result sets with the same "shape" - the number of columns, their *names* and types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CASE` returning results in 1 column so It can hold only 1 column name, for example:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @i = 1 THEN L.Id ELSE sl.id END AS LeadId
FROM TblName
```

If you want to have 2 different column names you should have separate columns:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @i = 1 THEN L.Id END AS LeadId,
       CASE WHEN @i <> 1 THEN sl.id END AS ServiceLeadId
FROM TblName
```

**UPDATE**

As per your comment you can use `IF` instead of `CASE`, something like:

```
DECLARE @i int = 1

IF (@i = 1)
BEGIN
    SELECT L.Id AS LeadId
    FROM TblName
END
ELSE
    SELECT sl.id AS ServiceLeadId
    FROM TblName
```

Comment: It returns only one column I know, but I need only one column with dynamic alias based on condition

Comment: Is it possible to perform in a single SQL

Comment: I don't think so that is possible.